# Error while executing query for custom fields using Tooling API

Tags: rest-api, custom-field, apexrest, tooling-api

I am trying to get all the custom fields, but on using the tooling API through APEX am getting the below error

- APEX

**Code** :

```
String baseURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v51.0/query?q=';
String endPoint = baseURL + 'SELECT+Id+from+customField';
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest hr = new HttpRequest();
hr.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
hr.setTimeout(60000);
hr.setEndpoint(endPoint);
hr.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse res = h.send(hr);
```

**ERROR** `System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]`

---

- **WorkBeanch**

Request : `/services/data/v51.0/query?q=select+Id+from+customFields`

**ERROR:**

```
 [ {
  "message" : "\nselect Id from customFields\n               ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:16\nsObject type 'customFields' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.",
  "errorCode" : "INVALID_TYPE"
} ]
```

Comment: You are not using tooling api.For tooling api URI should be ```/services/data/v51.0/tooling/```

Comment: I want to query all the custom fields as I can do it in developer console.

Answer (score 4):

The Tooling API uses a different base URI to the standard REST API: [Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_resources.htm)

> The base URI for each Tooling API REST resource is *http://domain/services/data/vXX.X/tooling/* where ***domain*** is a My Domain or a custom domain and ***vXX.X*** is the API version number. For example: https://MyDomainName.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v35.0/tooling/

So, as [kurunve commented](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/339215/error-while-executing-query-for-custom-fields-using-tooling-api#comment499452_339215), your anonyomous Apex code only needs a minimal modification to the url to work.

```
String baseURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v51.0/tooling/query?q=';
String endPoint = baseURL + 'SELECT+Id+from+customField';
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest hr = new HttpRequest();
hr.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
hr.setTimeout(60000);
hr.setEndpoint(endPoint);
hr.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse res = h.send(hr);
System.debug(res);
```